# Taking any number of space separed inputs till a new line

Tags: java, input

How should i take unknown number of space separated integers as inputs until the user presses enter in java and store inputs of each line in separate arrays.

For eg: If I have the following lines as input,

1 2 3 4 5

2 4 6 8 10

then one array stores 1st line (say) arr1={1,2,3,4,5}
and the next array stores 2nd line (say) arr2={2,4,6,8,10}

I have tried using scanner class to take the space separated integer inputs but am unable to switch to next array when a new line is encountered.

Comment: post your code, so that we can debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer[]> l = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many rows will you enter?");
        int numOfRows = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
            String[] arr = s.nextLine().split(" ");
            Integer[] arr2 = new Integer[arr.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                arr2[j] = Integer.parseInt(arr[j]);
            }
            l.add(arr2);
        }
        s.close();
        //Do whatever you want with l
    }
}
```

Comment: Improving on this I may suggest using while (s.hasNextLine()) rather than asking the user in advance. That being said, I thank you for pointing out scanner.nextLine, i was not familiar with it.

Comment: No problem, but how would he implement that, since I'm assuming he is reading from the console input

Comment: A valid point, in that case I suppose he will have to ask the user for that info.

Comment: @RoyShahaf if this answer helped you please consider upvoting it and marking it as correct! Have a nice day!

Comment: Id like to thank the first upvoter for getting me over the 1000 rep milestone!

Comment: Thnx a lot,your ans helped me. I didn't know about the split() func. However, sorry I can't upvote you as I am a new user. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for an unknown number of integers per line I would suggest a less size-bound data structure, maybe a list.

Secondly, a BufferedReader seems a better choice if you wish to read lines (using it's method readLine). After a line is read you can use string.split(" ") to get the integers.

Comment: He's better of using a Scanner, like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get the input until an empty line, then turn the line to `String` array using space as delimeter. Then parse each element to `int` and put it to a temporary `ArrayList<Integer>`. The parsed ints in `ArrayList<Integer>` will be put inside the main `ArrayList`.

The structure of the `ArrayList` will be `ArrayList` of `ArrayList<Integer>`

```
import java.util.*;

public class MultiLine {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("Input:");

        // main ArrayList
        ArrayList < ArrayList<Integer> > lst = new ArrayList < ArrayList<Integer> >();

        // input process
        while ( sc.hasNextLine() ) {

            String line = sc.nextLine();

            // stops input if line is empty
            if ( line.equals("") )
                break;

            // splits line to String array, using space as delimiter
            String[] splittedLine = line.split(" ");

            // temporary ArrayList that will parse each number from lines seperated by space
            ArrayList <Integer> temp = new ArrayList <Integer>();

            // parses each String of splittedLine to int, adds it to temp ArrayList
            for( String num : splittedLine ) {
                try {
                    temp.add( Integer.parseInt(num) );
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // adds temp ArrayList to lst
            lst.add( temp );
        }
        System.out.println( lst );
    }
}
```

***Sample Run***

```
Input:
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
12 14
895 623 1245 1

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [12, 14], [895, 623, 1245, 1]]
```